# Kibana reports fail with "waitForSelector [data-shared-item],[data-shared-items-count] failed on..."

Tags: kibana, puppeteer

Kibana 7.2.0
HeadlessChrome 74.0.3723.0

Reports fail with the log message `waitForSelector [data-shared-item],[data-shared-items-count] failed on http://0.0.0.0:5601/login?next=%2Fs%2Finfrastructure...`. Given the function name `waitForSelector`, I am guessing that this is a message from the HeadlessChrome browser.

While I am guessing that the request shown in the error message is failing in this case, it does return successfully and immediately if I visit the URL from a browser while logged in, or from curl with some user credentials ie `curl -u user:pass -H 'kbn-version: 7.2.0' -XGET ...`.

It appears from the Kibana logs that several preceding requests are being made on behalf of the report, and are returned successfully with 200 or 304 responses.

Here are some of the Kibana logs:

```
{
  "type": "response",
  "@timestamp": "2019-07-24T19:41:16Z",
  "tags": [
    "api"
  ],
  "pid": 1,
  "method": "post",
  "statusCode": 200,
  "req": {
    "url": "/api/reporting/generate/png?jobParams=(browserTimezone%3AAmerica%2FLos_Angeles%2Clayout%3A(dimensions%3A(height%3A698%2Cwidth%3A1258)%2Cid%3Apng)%2CobjectType%3Avisualization%2CrelativeUrl%3A'%2Fapp%2Fkibana%23%2Fvisualize%2Fedit%2F6f653c90-8ef8-11e9-bcc9-fbde2741907a%3F_g%3D()%26_a%3D(filters%3A!!()%2Clinked%3A!!f%2Cquery%3A(language%3Akuery%2Cquery%3A!'!')%2CuiState%3A(vis%3A(legendOpen%3A!!t))%2Cvis%3A(aggs%3A!!((enabled%3A!!t%2Cid%3A!'1!'%2Cparams%3A(field%3Arabbitmq.queue.messages.total.count)%2Cschema%3Ametric%2Ctype%3Amax)%2C(enabled%3A!!t%2Cid%3A!'2!'%2Cparams%3A(drop_partials%3A!!f%2Cextended_bounds%3A()%2Cfield%3A!'%40timestamp!'%2Cinterval%3Aauto%2Cmin_doc_count%3A1%2CuseNormalizedEsInterval%3A!!t)%2Cschema%3Asegment%2Ctype%3Adate_histogram)%2C(enabled%3A!!t%2Cid%3A!'3!'%2Cparams%3A(field%3Arabbitmq.queue.name%2CmissingBucket%3A!!f%2CmissingBucketLabel%3AMissing%2Corder%3Adesc%2CorderBy%3A!'1!'%2CotherBucket%3A!!f%2CotherBucketLabel%3AOther%2Csize%3A15)%2Cschema%3Agroup%2Ctype%3Aterms))%2Cparams%3A(addLegend%3A!!t%2CaddTimeMarker%3A!!t%2CaddTooltip%3A!!t%2CcategoryAxes%3A!!((id%3ACategoryAxis-1%2Clabels%3A(show%3A!!t%2Ctruncate%3A100)%2Cposition%3Abottom%2Cscale%3A(type%3Alinear)%2Cshow%3A!!t%2Cstyle%3A()%2Ctitle%3A()%2Ctype%3Acategory))%2Cgrid%3A(categoryLines%3A!!t%2CvalueAxis%3A!!n)%2ClegendPosition%3Aright%2CseriesParams%3A!!((data%3A(id%3A!'1!'%2Clabel%3A!'Max%2Brabbitmq.queue.messages.total.count!')%2CdrawLinesBetweenPoints%3A!!t%2Cinterpolate%3Acardinal%2Cmode%3Anormal%2Cshow%3Atrue%2CshowCircles%3A!!t%2Ctype%3Aline%2CvalueAxis%3AValueAxis-1))%2Ctimes%3A!!()%2Ctype%3Aline%2CvalueAxes%3A!!((id%3AValueAxis-1%2Clabels%3A(filter%3A!!f%2Crotate%3A0%2Cshow%3A!!t%2Ctruncate%3A100)%2Cname%3ALeftAxis-1%2Cposition%3Aleft%2Cscale%3A(mode%3Anormal%2Ctype%3Alinear)%2Cshow%3A!!t%2Cstyle%3A()%2Ctitle%3A(text%3A!'Max%2Brabbitmq.queue.messages.total.count!')%2Ctype%3Avalue)))%2Ctitle%3A!'RabbitMQ%2BQueued%2BMessages!'%2Ctype%3Aline))'%2Ctitle%3A'RabbitMQ%20Queued%20Messages')",
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
      "host": "kibana.XXX",
      "accept": "*/*",
      "kbn-version": "7.2.0",
      "user-agent": "curl/7.54.0",
      "x-forwarded-for": "10.X.X.X",
      "x-forwarded-port": "80",
      "x-forwarded-proto": "http",
      "content-length": "0",
      "connection": "close"
    },
    "remoteAddress": "10.X.X.X",
    "userAgent": "10.X.X.X"
  },
  "res": {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "responseTime": 60,
    "contentLength": 9
  },
  "message": "POST /api/reporting/generate/png?jobParams=(browserTimezone%3AAmerica%2FLos_Angeles%2Clayout%3A(dimensions%3A(height%3A698%2Cwidth%3A1258)%2Cid%3Apng)%2CobjectType%3Avisualization%2CrelativeUrl%3A'%2Fapp%2Fkibana%23%2Fvisualize%2Fedit%2F6f653c90-8ef8-11e9-bcc9-fbde2741907a%3F_g%3D()%26_a%3D(filters%3A!!()%2Clinked%3A!!f%2Cquery%3A(language%3Akuery%2Cquery%3A!'!')%2CuiState%3A(vis%3A(legendOpen%3A!!t))%2Cvis%3A(aggs%3A!!((enabled%3A!!t%2Cid%3A!'1!'%2Cparams%3A(field%3Arabbitmq.queue.messages.total.count)%2Cschema%3Ametric%2Ctype%3Amax)%2C(enabled%3A!!t%2Cid%3A!'2!'%2Cparams%3A(drop_partials%3A!!f%2Cextended_bounds%3A()%2Cfield%3A!'%40timestamp!'%2Cinterval%3Aauto%2Cmin_doc_count%3A1%2CuseNormalizedEsInterval%3A!!t)%2Cschema%3Asegment%2Ctype%3Adate_histogram)%2C(enabled%3A!!t%2Cid%3A!'3!'%2Cparams%3A(field%3Arabbitmq.queue.name%2CmissingBucket%3A!!f%2CmissingBucketLabel%3AMissing%2Corder%3Adesc%2CorderBy%3A!'1!'%2CotherBucket%3A!!f%2CotherBucketLabel%3AOther%2Csize%3A15)%2Cschema%3Agroup%2Ctype%3Aterms))%2Cparams%3A(addLegend%3A!!t%2CaddTimeMarker%3A!!t%2CaddTooltip%3A!!t%2CcategoryAxes%3A!!((id%3ACategoryAxis-1%2Clabels%3A(show%3A!!t%2Ctruncate%3A100)%2Cposition%3Abottom%2Cscale%3A(type%3Alinear)%2Cshow%3A!!t%2Cstyle%3A()%2Ctitle%3A()%2Ctype%3Acategory))%2Cgrid%3A(categoryLines%3A!!t%2CvalueAxis%3A!!n)%2ClegendPosition%3Aright%2CseriesParams%3A!!((data%3A(id%3A!'1!'%2Clabel%3A!'Max%2Brabbitmq.queue.messages.total.count!')%2CdrawLinesBetweenPoints%3A!!t%2Cinterpolate%3Acardinal%2Cmode%3Anormal%2Cshow%3Atrue%2CshowCircles%3A!!t%2Ctype%3Aline%2CvalueAxis%3AValueAxis-1))%2Ctimes%3A!!()%2Ctype%3Aline%2CvalueAxes%3A!!((id%3AValueAxis-1%2Clabels%3A(filter%3A!!f%2Crotate%3A0%2Cshow%3A!!t%2Ctruncate%3A100)%2Cname%3ALeftAxis-1%2Cposition%3Aleft%2Cscale%3A(mode%3Anormal%2Ctype%3Alinear)%2Cshow%3A!!t%2Cstyle%3A()%2Ctitle%3A(text%3A!'Max%2Brabbitmq.queue.messages.total.count!')%2Ctype%3Avalue)))%2Ctitle%3A!'RabbitMQ%2BQueued%2BMessages!'%2Ctype%3Aline))'%2Ctitle%3A'RabbitMQ%20Queued%20Messages') 200 60ms - 9.0B"
}
{
  "type": "response",
  "@timestamp": "2019-07-24T19:41:18Z",
  "tags": [],
  "pid": 1,
  "method": "get",
  "statusCode": 302,
  "req": {
    "url": "/app/kibana",
    "method": "get",
    "headers": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0:5601",
      "connection": "keep-alive",
      "pragma": "no-cache",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
      "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/74.0.3723.0 Safari/537.36",
      "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
      "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate"
    },
    "remoteAddress": "127.0.0.1",
    "userAgent": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "res": {
    "statusCode": 302,
    "responseTime": 3,
    "contentLength": 9
  },
  "message": "GET /app/kibana 302 3ms - 9.0B"
}
{
  "type": "response",
  "@timestamp": "2019-07-24T19:41:18Z",
  "tags": [],
  "pid": 1,
  "method": "get",
  "statusCode": 200,
  "req": {
    "url": "/login?next=%2Fs%2Finfrastructure%2Fapp%2Fkibana",
    "method": "get",
    "headers": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0:5601",
      "connection": "keep-alive",
      "pragma": "no-cache",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
      "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/74.0.3723.0 Safari/537.36",
      "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
      "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate"
    },
    "remoteAddress": "127.0.0.1",
    "userAgent": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "res": {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "responseTime": 32,
    "contentLength": 9
  },
  "message": "GET /login?next=%2Fs%2Finfrastructure%2Fapp%2Fkibana 200 32ms - 9.0B"
}
```

[...]

```
{
  "type": "response",
  "@timestamp": "2019-07-24T19:41:20Z",
  "tags": [],
  "pid": 1,
  "method": "get",
  "statusCode": 200,
  "req": {
    "url": "/ui/fonts/inter_ui/Inter-UI-SemiBold.woff2",
    "method": "get",
    "headers": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0:5601",
      "connection": "keep-alive",
      "pragma": "no-cache",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "origin": "http://0.0.0.0:5601",
      "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/74.0.3723.0 Safari/537.36",
      "accept": "*/*",
      "referer": "http://0.0.0.0:5601/login?next=%2Fs%2Finfrastructure%2Fapp%2Fkibana",
      "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate"
    },
    "remoteAddress": "127.0.0.1",
    "userAgent": "127.0.0.1",
    "referer": "http://0.0.0.0:5601/login?next=%2Fs%2Finfrastructure%2Fapp%2Fkibana"
  },
  "res": {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "responseTime": 4,
    "contentLength": 9
  },
  "message": "GET /ui/fonts/inter_ui/Inter-UI-SemiBold.woff2 200 4ms - 9.0B"
}
{
  "type": "log",
  "@timestamp": "2019-07-24T19:43:18Z",
  "tags": [
    "reporting",
    "browser-driver",
    "chromium-driver-factory",
    "headless-chromium-driver",
    "error"
  ],
  "pid": 1,
  "message": "waitForSelector [data-shared-item],[data-shared-items-count] failed on http://0.0.0.0:5601/login?next=%2Fs%2Finfrastructure%2Fapp%2Fkibana#/visualize/edit/6f653c90-8ef8-11e9-bcc9-fbde2741907a?_g=()&_a=(filters:!(),linked:!f,query:(language:kuery,query:''),uiState:(vis:(legendOpen:!t)),vis:(aggs:!((enabled:!t,id:'1',params:(field:rabbitmq.queue.messages.total.count),schema:metric,type:max),(enabled:!t,id:'2',params:(drop_partials:!f,extended_bounds:(),field:'@timestamp',interval:auto,min_doc_count:1,useNormalizedEsInterval:!t),schema:segment,type:date_histogram),(enabled:!t,id:'3',params:(field:rabbitmq.queue.name,missingBucket:!f,missingBucketLabel:Missing,order:desc,orderBy:'1',otherBucket:!f,otherBucketLabel:Other,size:15),schema:group,type:terms)),params:(addLegend:!t,addTimeMarker:!t,addTooltip:!t,categoryAxes:!((id:CategoryAxis-1,labels:(show:!t,truncate:100),position:bottom,scale:(type:linear),show:!t,style:(),title:(),type:category)),grid:(categoryLines:!t,valueAxis:!n),legendPosition:right,seriesParams:!((data:(id:'1',label:'Max%20rabbitmq.queue.messages.total.count'),drawLinesBetweenPoints:!t,interpolate:cardinal,mode:normal,show:true,showCircles:!t,type:line,valueAxis:ValueAxis-1)),times:!(),type:line,valueAxes:!((id:ValueAxis-1,labels:(filter:!f,rotate:0,show:!t,truncate:100),name:LeftAxis-1,position:left,scale:(mode:normal,type:linear),show:!t,style:(),title:(text:'Max%20rabbitmq.queue.messages.total.count'),type:value))),title:'RabbitMQ%20Queued%20Messages',type:line))&forceNow=2019-07-24T19:41:16.435Z"
}
```

Comment: Same thing here, did you solve this?